# How to use a placeholder with an NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am currently using this code to put some  text on the screen

```
   userOutput.text=@"";
```

I want to be able to display an int variable in the string, like you do with printf in C with the %d placeholders.  How do I do this with an NSString

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int whatever = 42;
userOutput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", whatever];
```

Answer (score 2):

use NSString's `+stringWithFormat:` method:

```
 userOutput.text= [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 100];
```

It uses exactly the same format specifiers as printf function in c.

Comment: And besides the C `printf` format specifiers, you can use `%@`, to print the `-description` of any object.